# Spring boot + Qurartz + Oracle problem with JobStoreTX

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, yaml, quartz

I´m creating an application with Spring boot + Quartz + Oracle and i would like to save the scheduling in the database (persistent, in case the server crashes). With RAMJobStore works fine, but when I try to use JobStoreTX it doesn't work, it always uses RAMJobStore, where colud be the problem?. I'm surely making a lot of mistakes, but it's my first application with spring boot + Quartz, can you give me an idea?

The events will be created dynamically, receiving the information in the controller.

**application.yaml** (In addition to Quartz, the application connects to the database to query tables, but the application and Quartz will use the same database)

```
hibernate:
  globally_quoted_identifiers: true
  show_sql: true
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: ${hibernate.logging}
  pattern:
    console: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
server:
  port: ${port}
spring:
  activemq:
    broker-url: ${activemq-url}
    password: ${activemq-password}
    user: ${activemq-user}
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: ${driverClassName}
    password: ${ddbb-password}
    jdbcUrl: ${ddbb-url}
    username: ${ddbb-user}
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO
          jobStore:
            useProperties: true
            isClustered: false
            clusterCheckinInterval: 5000
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
            dataSource: quartzDataSource
          dataSource:
            quartzDataSource:
              driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
              URL: ${ddbb-url}
              user: ${ddbb-user}
              password: ${ddbb-password}
```

**Class SchedulerConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(new AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory());
        return schedulerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Scheduler scheduler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws SchedulerException {
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory(applicationContext).getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        return scheduler;
    }

   @Bean
   @QuartzDataSource
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
       public DataSource quartzDataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }
}
```

**class AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactor**

```
public class AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements
    ApplicationContextAware{
    
    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }
    

}
```

**Job class**

```
@Component
public class CampaignJob implements Job{
    
        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
            System.out.println("Hi, the job works");
        
    }

}
```

**The class where the scheduler it´s created**

```
public class ManagerServiceImpl implements ManagerService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProducerQueue producer;
    
    @Autowired
    private ManagementDatabase managementDatabase;
    
    @Autowired
    private Scheduler scheduler;
    
    @Override
    public String processCampaign(ScheduleCampaign scheduleCampaign) {
        try {
            ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(scheduleCampaign.getDateTime(), scheduleCampaign.getTimeZone());
            JobDetail jobDetail = buildJobDetail(scheduleCampaign);
            Trigger trigger = buildJobTrigger(jobDetail, dateTime);
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error creating the scheduler: "+e);
        }
        
        return "Scheduler created";
    }
    

     private JobDetail buildJobDetail(ScheduleCampaign scheduleCampaign) {
            JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
            System.out.println("Function: buildJobDetail -  campaign value: "+scheduleCampaign.getCampaign());
            jobDataMap.put("campaign", scheduleCampaign.getCampaign());
            return JobBuilder.newJob(CampaignJob.class)
                    .withIdentity(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "campaign-jobs")
                    .requestRecovery(true)
                    .storeDurably(true)
                    .withDescription("campaign job planned")
                    .usingJobData(jobDataMap)
                    .storeDurably()
                    .build();
        }

     private Trigger buildJobTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, ZonedDateTime startAt) {
            return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .forJob(jobDetail)
                    .withIdentity(jobDetail.getKey().getName(), "campaign-triggers")
                    .withDescription("campaign job Trigger")
                    .startAt(Date.from(startAt.toInstant()))
                    .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                    .build();
        }

    

}
```

**Logs**

```
2020-12-28 16:16:08 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2020-12-28 16:16:09 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

2020-12-28 16:16:09 INFO o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]

2020-12-28 16:16:10 INFO org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.23.Final

2020-12-28 16:16:10 INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor

2020-12-28 16:16:10 INFO o.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl

2020-12-28 16:16:10 INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.

2020-12-28 16:16:10 INFO org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.

2020-12-28 16:16:10 INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'schedulerFactory' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'

Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.

NOT STARTED.

Currently in standby mode.

Number of jobs executed: 0

Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.

Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to autowire your app default dataSource, if you are pointing the same DB for quartz jobs as well.

The below configuration worked for me with PostgreSQL

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
JobFactory jobFactory;

@Bean
public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return jobFactory;
}

@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```